# android data binding cannot find method get() in class Statistic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a model class like this

```
data class FixtureById(
    @SerializedName("get")
    val `get`: String?,
    @SerializedName("response")
    val response: List<Response?>?,
) {

    data class Response(
        @SerializedName("statistics")
        val statistics: List<Statistic?>?,
    ) {

        data class Statistic(
            @SerializedName("statistics")
            val statistics: List<Statistic?>?,
            @SerializedName("team")
            val team: Team?
        ) {
            data class Statistic(
                @SerializedName("type")
                val type: String?,
                @SerializedName("value")
                val value: Int?
            )

            data class Team(
                @SerializedName("id")
                val id: Int?,
                @SerializedName("logo")
                val logo: String?,
                @SerializedName("name")
                val name: String?
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and in the layout I'm using dataBinding like this

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <data>
            <variable
                name="statistic"
                type="com.mobile.sportology.models.football.FixtureById.Response" />
        </data>
    
        <TextView
                            android:text="@{statistic.statistics.get(0).statistics.get(9).value}"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="@color/holo_green_light"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</layout>
```

and here's how I set the data

```
responseState.data?.response?.get(0)?.let { statistic ->
                        binding.statistic = statistic
                    }
```

then when I run the app I get this error

```
cannot find method get() in class Statistic
```

but when I try another type of data (other than `FixtureById`), the code compiles, I do not what exactly I have missed

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this and thank you in advance

Comment: Do you see that you have two different classes named Statistic? That is unbelievably confusing. Also it recursively contains a list of itself. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Tenfour04 that is the response of the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, thank you @Tenfour04 you gave me the hint, cheers

simply change the most inner `Statistic` class name to any other name.
what happened is that the compiler confused with these similar names although when you put the cursor on any `Statistic` class it will highlight the other `Statistic` outer or inner class